# Python 3.4.3 NameError: name "" is not defined

Tags: python, input, nameerror

This is using Python 3.4.3. I am very aware that this is a very common issue but I am an extremely inexperienced programmer and on all the other answers people talk about things that I don't understand at all. This is very basic, just for some practice and yet it is constantly having this error, and despite searching through over and over, I can find no explanation. Here it is:

```
def choose ():
    choice = input("Choose one - +, -, / or *.")
    if (choice != '+' and choice != '-' and choice != '/' and choice != '*'):
         print ("Please give a valid answer.")
         pass
    if (choice == '+'):
        add()
    if (choice == '-'):
         subtract()
    if (choice == '/'):
         divide()
    if (choice == '*'):
        multiply()

main()
```

The functions appear later on. Whenever I run it, it says 'NameError: name 'choice' is not defined', which is very frustrating. I think that placing the code into this messed with the indents, so sorry if my indents are all messed up, they were fine. Thanks if you can help :) I need a very straightforward answer please, still very early on.

Comment: _"I think that placing the code into this messed with the indents"_ Ok, well, go ahead and fix it and then we can help diagnose your actual problem.

Comment: If your first if-statement is indented at the same level as the def-statement then if-statement does not belong to the def-statement.  That means that variable names local to the def-statement will not be seen by the if-statement.

Comment: An asside:  `if (choice != '+' and choice != '-' and choice != '/' and choice != '*')` can be changed to `if choice not in ['+', '-', '/', '*']` or even `if choice not in '+-/*'`.

Comment: In addition to fixing the indentation in your question to match your actual indentation, please provide the full traceback -- not just the error message at the end.  With those two improvements, it should be easy for us to give you a good answer.

Comment: Voted to close as "unclear what you are asking" because the question has not been edited with the requested clarification.

Comment: How should someone be able to write working code if he/she can't even post a question with proper indentation?

Answer (score -1):

In Python indentation is important! Use 4 spaces per level:

```
def choose ():
    choice = input ("Choose one - +, -, / or *.")
    if (choice != '+' and choice != '-' and choice != '/' and choice != '*'):
        print ("Please give a valid answer.")
    if (choice == '+'):
        add ()
    if (choice == '-'):
        subtract ()
    if (choice == '/'):
        divide ()
    if (choice == '*'):
        multiply ()

main ()
```

Comment: This answer leaves out that you not only changed the indentation to four spaces (which while nice is unimportant) but that you changed the indentation to make the if-statements fall inside of the `choose` function.  Your answer would be improved with the addition of an explanation.